# displaying last element in a foreach loop several times

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

Hy there.
I have a unit with 7 room, but only 5 of them have pictures in it. My goal is to display each of them in the right place, ie 1#room->1img, 2#room->1img, 3#room->3img, 4#room->2img, 5#room->1img, 6#room->0img, 7#room->0img. Here is my array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [large] =>room_galleries/4/large/XWKgkS_a503fd0054f4c6a04e72d95cef5d8b6a.jpg
            [thumb] =>room_galleries/4/thumb/XWKgkS_a503fd0054f4c6a04e72d95cef5d8b6a.jpg
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [large] => room_galleries/13/large/96Hk2r_6e2507fabb7313d18d9a694eda740337.jpg
            [thumb] => room_galleries/13/thumb/96Hk2r_6e2507fabb7313d18d9a694eda740337.jpg
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [large] => room_galleries/38/large/HXJTWL_98e71e7fbc9bab7096f0387b2ffa9ab9.jpg
            [thumb] => room_galleries/38/thumb/HXJTWL_98e71e7fbc9bab7096f0387b2ffa9ab9.jpg
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [large] =>room_galleries/38/large/XCquAP_5ccd9c6af4501a1c81b1e6b532100036.jpg
            [thumb] =>room_galleries/38/thumb/XCquAP_5ccd9c6af4501a1c81b1e6b532100036.jpg
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [large] => room_galleries/38/large/iDe0SN_6dcf2e3c9dc2180cbed5c98f0adbb0e9.jpg
            [thumb] => room_galleries/38/thumb/iDe0SN_6dcf2e3c9dc2180cbed5c98f0adbb0e9.jpg
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [large] => room_galleries/39/large/FDM6JV_63243ea8328f4ba74200ea3c2d32aa0c.jpg
            [thumb] => room_galleries/39/thumb/FDM6JV_63243ea8328f4ba74200ea3c2d32aa0c.jpg
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [large] => room_galleries/39/large/ccNOdB_a12501222468f3e38f05433c002b8851.jpg
            [thumb] => room_galleries/39/thumb/ccNOdB_a12501222468f3e38f05433c002b8851.jpg
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [large] => room_galleries/41/large/IosSy8_e4d6ff02cc21212c6cf6e616619f11b6.jpg
            [thumb] => room_galleries/41/thumb/IosSy8_e4d6ff02cc21212c6cf6e616619f11b6.jpg
        )

)
```

Here is my php code:

```
if( !empty( $r['images'])){
            $images = unserialize( $r['images'] );
            foreach( $images as $img ){
                $galleries[$r['roomID']][] = array(
                    'large' => ROOM_GALLERY_HTTP . $r['roomID'] . '/large/' . $img,
                    'thumb' =>  ROOM_GALLERY_HTTP . $r['roomID'] . '/thumb/' . $img,
                );  
            }
            print_r( $galleries[$r['roomID']] ); // the array above
            $tpl->set( 'galleries', $galleries[$r['roomID']] ); // set a tag named galleries for my template
        }
```

My problem is that it displays the last element in the loop 7 times.:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [large] => room_galleries/41/large/IosSy8_e4d6ff02cc21212c6cf6e616619f11b6.jpg
            [thumb] => room_galleries/41/thumb/IosSy8_e4d6ff02cc21212c6cf6e616619f11b6.jpg
        )

)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: above result is of "print_r( $galleries[$r['roomID']] );" ?

Comment: ok, so your php array is correct. how you are using it in template?

Comment: <loop:galleries>
     <div class="thumb_wrap">
      <a class="gallery" title="Room gallery" href="<tag:galleries[].large />">
       <img class="thumb" alt="Room gallery" src="<tag:galleries[].thumb />" />
      </a>
     </div>
    </loop:galleries>

Comment: can you show your html output?

Comment: <div class="thumb_wrap">
      <a class="gallery" title="Galerie camere" href="http://i.cazare7.ro/room_galleries/41/large/IosSy8_e4d6ff02cc21212c6cf6e616619f11b6.jpg">
       <img class="thumb" alt="Galerie camere" src="http://i.cazare7.ro/room_galleries/41/thumb/IosSy8_e4d6ff02cc21212c6cf6e616619f11b6.jpg" />
      </a>
     </div>

Comment: which framework or cms you are using?

Comment: Have you tried to reset array $images before foreach statement?

Comment: @Tinku Rana - i use bTemplate

Comment: @SergiyT. -Yes, same output

Comment: ok, I've no idea about this template engine. But can you use php function like print_r in tpl file to check out put like in smarty?

Comment: @TinkuRana - unfortunately i can't:|

Comment: Thanks for everybody, who gived me a help...I've solved it btw:D...it was something in that part when I'm displaying the content in bTemplate, I've had a loop in a loop and that messed up my things a little bit:P, despite that my array was correct.